# Print the nth member among five members’ height using Structure

Tags: c, arrays, structure

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct member {
    char name[20];
    int age;
    char sex;
    int height;
};  


int main(void)
{
int i,j;
struct member input[5]={0,};
int tot, rank, max=0;
int max2[5]={0,};
float res;

for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    scanf("%s ", input[i].name);
    scanf("%d %c %d", &input[i].age, &input[i].sex, &input[i].height);
    getchar();
}
    scanf("%d", &rank);
    max =input[0].height;

 for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
        if(max>=input[j].height)
            max=max;
        else
            max=input[j].height;
    }

     max2[i]=max;

     for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
        if(max==input[j].height)
            input[j].height*=(-1);
      }

     max=-1;
 }


 for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    if(max2[rank]== input[i].height)
        printf("%s %d %c %d\n",input[i].name, input[i].age, input[i].sex,input[i].height);

}



    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();


return 0;

}
```

The result printed of above my code is nothing...Even the height inputted becomes negative number..
What's wrong with this program? 
Input & Print should be the same like example image.......
please help!

Comment: were you aware that [`scanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) returns a value? You might find that helpful..

Comment: I/O in C is non-trivial.  If this is a learning exercise in C (for constructs other than I/O) I'd recommend hard coding your inputs within your code, so you can focus on your loops, arrays, structures, and other good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The first `scanf` should be fixed

```
scanf("%s ", input[i].name);
```

In the second `scanf`, the `input[i].sex` is a `char` type so you have to use `"%c"` instead of `%s`

```
scanf("%d %s %d", &input[i].age, &input[i].sex, &input[i].height);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d %c %d", &input[i].age, &input[i].sex, &input[i].height);
```

Comment: yes i just edit "%s" to "%c" but the result is same.. nothing.. I think the problem is inside for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    if(max2[rank]== input[i].height)
        printf("%s %d %c %d\n",input[i].name, input[i].age, input[i].sex,input[i].height);

}

Comment: @anna even your first scanf contain problem. see muy answer it's updated

Comment: thank u.. I fixed it all you said but still the problem happens.. T_T

Comment: That's *a* problem, but it's defiantly *not* the only reason the code doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

You have a *lot* of problems here:

1) You're taking the wrong parameters from `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%s ", input[i].name); // You don't need a & for a string
scanf("%d %c %d", &input[i].age, &input[i].sex, &input[i].height); // you need %c for a
                                                                   // character
```

2) You're using `for(i=1;i<=5;i++)` to access an array of 5 elements, by doing this you're overflowing the array (it should be 0 to 4, not 1 to 5)

3) This is a nit-pick but:

```
if(max>=input[j].height)
     max=max;
```

that is totally pointless. You don't need to set a variable to itself, just invert the logic (`<`) and only do the `else` case.

4) You set all the `input[x].height`'s to the negative of the value they're originally set to here:

```
input[j].height*=(-1);
```

Then you check to see if that is the same as the original values which you stored in `max2[]` before printing here:

```
if(max2[rank]== input[i].height)
    printf("%s %d %s %d\n",input[i].name, input[i].age, input[i].sex,input[i].height);
```

Well, that's never going to happen, so you'll never print *anything*

5) `fflush(stdin);` is not a well defined operation on most systems and could lead to undefined behavior, so don't do it.